# Left joins where there is an OR clause

Tags: sql, redquerybuilder

Consider the following Query in RQB using Foreign Keys

I have two tables, `companies` and `weather`.

The foreign key joins the `weather` to `company` on zip code

The RQB I am entering is:

```
Employees Total - Greater Than - 1000

OR

FK Weather.Temp < 50
```

The SQL that is generated by RQB is (approximately):

```
SELECT * FROM companies
INNER JOIN weather
ON companies.zip = weather.zip
WHERE company.employees > 1000
OR
weather.temp < 50
```

The issue is that from the UI perspective if I specify an `OR` and use a foreign key in the `OR` `WHERE` clause, I should get a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`. I would expect the `INNER JOIN` in the case of an `AND`, but an `OR` requires a `LEFT JOIN` so I get all the companies with `Employees > 1000` and I also get all of the company records with a match of the company records where `Temp` was `< 50`

My question is, is there a way to get RQB to output a `LEFT JOIN` on a foreign key where the referenced table is used with an `OR`?

Comment: Why would you expect a `left join`?  A `full outer join` would make sense, but why prefer one table over the other?

Comment: I believe you are correct, but full outer join is not supported by MySQL (which I'm currently using), which complicates the problem a bit.  You can emulate it by something like: SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id

Answer (score 0):

Not with the current code I'm afraid. Best to raise an issue?

Could start to get tricky as that join could go on to be used by other things? Although nulls should resolve to false.

Comment: I will raise an issue, but I'm not sure it's solvable in a technically correct way, per Gordon's comment above.  It would need to be emulated, per my follow-up comment.  I'll open an issue on github and we can discuss it further and see if there's a solution that's not a huge deal.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with mysql. How about subqueries?

Comment: A left join union'd w/ a right join achieves the same affect.  I put details in the issue on github https://github.com/salk31/RedQueryBuilder/issues/35